# Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with $\text{rank}(A) = 1$. Prove that for some column $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and row $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $A = uv$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with $\text{rank}(A) = 1$. Prove that for some nonzero column vector $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and a nonzero row vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the matrix $A$ can be written in terms of the outer product 
\begin{equation}
A = uv.
\end{equation}

I do not know where to start, can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $A$ is rank $1$ if and only if all its eigenvalues are equal to zero except 1. That is for any vector $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$, we have
\begin{equation}
u = \frac{1}{\lambda} A\tilde{v} = A v 
\end{equation}
in which $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of $A$. This is true for unit vectors (all entries are zero except one entry is 1). Then you can show that $A = v u^\top$

Next step you need to show that if $A = u v^\top$ then it must be rank $1$. To do this you need to show that for any vector $v$ in  $\mathbb{R}^n$, $Av$ is a scalar multiple of $u$